# How do I check whether an e-mail exists in the Firebase database using Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have seen some answers to this question using a Java implementation; however, I wasn't able to convert it successfully. The Java implementation seems to use a try, catch approach to determine whether the FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException is ran into or not. But from researching online, it seems try, catch is obsolete in Kotlin.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(){it:Task<AuthResult>
             if(!it.isSuccessful)
```

This is the only piece of code I have so far. I appreciate all help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try/catch is not obsolete in Kotlin.  It still works essentially the same way.  It's just not very useful when working with the asynchronous APIs provided by Firebase and Play services.

The Firebase APIs are all asynchronous, so you need to check for errors in the callbacks that you attach to the Task object returned from the call.  This is the same for both Java and Kotlin.  You might want to learn more about the [Task API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) in order to better deal with Firebase APIs that return a Task to represent asynchronous work.  In the code you've shown, you check for errors in an onComplete listener by looking at the exception object in the result if it wasn't successful:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener() { it:Task<AuthResult>
             if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                 val exception = it.exception
                 // do something with this exception, according to the Firestore API docs
             }
```

Comment: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(){
                if(!it.isSuccessful)
                    try{
                        it.exception
                    }
                    catch ()

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried this, and the "try" statement seemed to work. However, I can't get the catch to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You're not using try/catch correctly.  As I said, it's not helpful here.  Use the pattern I established in my example.

Comment: sorry, i'm not quite sure how to move on with the "do something with this exception" you made. how do i tie this into FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException?

Comment: You can check its type against the type of exception(s) you want to check for.  In kotlin the keyword is `is`.  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: i think i see where you're pointing at. 
would it bew something along  the lines of 
if(exception is FirebaseAuthUserCollisonException){
Toast.makeText(context: this, test: "this email already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()